# How to define when to stop and start for /f loop in batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

so I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to define when to stop and start a `for /f loop` For an example make it read only 37 lines and then stop. But at the same time I can set when it starts to read. So it's not necessarily the first 37 lines. But some 37 lines in the middle of the document as an example.
I'm using the following code

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="
0^<"decryption_key.txt"') do set "%%G=%%H"
```

to read a document and split text into variables and values on each side of an "=" sign.
The text document looks like this:

```
Date encrypted: 16/06/2021 Time: 23.51.19,70
key_a='
key_b=..:.
key_c=''::
key_d=*:::
key_e='''
key_f=::''
key_g=:***
key_h=**
key_i=....
key_j=':::
key_k=..
key_l=.
key_m=''''
key_n=**::
key_o=:::.
key_p=:::'
key_q=*
key_r=.::.
key_s='':'
key_t=***:
key_u=:..:
key_v=::..
key_w=:'''
key_x=::**
key_y=:::*
key_z=...
key_zero=...:
key_one=''
key_two=..::
key_three=.:::
key_four=''':
key_five=.:..
key_six=::::
key_seven=:...
key_eight=****
key_nine=***
Date encrypted: 17/06/2021 Time:  0.14.31,56
key_a=....
key_b=***:
key_c=::''
key_d=..:.
key_e=**::
key_f=...:
key_g=':::
key_h=:...
key_i=***
key_j=''::
key_k='''
key_l=.::.
key_m=*:::
key_n=:::*
key_o=**
key_p=::::
key_q=...
key_r=:::'
key_s=*
key_t=:::.
key_u='
key_v='':'
key_w=''
key_x=..::
key_y=::..
key_z=****
key_zero=:***
key_one=..
key_two=''''
key_three=:'''
key_four=.:::
key_five=.:..
key_six=''':
key_seven=:..:
key_eight=.
key_nine=::**
```

But I need to be able to define when it stops reading the document so that it doesn't overwrite previous values if more values for the same variable is defined lower down in that document. And at the same time I need to be able to define when it starts to read in case I do only want it to use the values lower down. So basically. How do I make it read only 37 lines and then stop, and start after "X" amount of lines within that document?

Comment: Your file does not match the layout of the one I provided that code for, that one used the format `KeyName==KeyValue`. For the layout you're now supplying, with just one `=` character, that example code is over complex! It is far easier when you write a question to be completely honest with those trying to assist you, so that they can, not only provide a solution, but can do so using robust and efficient code. For this particular question, I'd want to know more about your input text file, why you're formatting/creating it like that, because changing things could remove your issue completely.

Comment: The text file is being created by another batch file, and each time I open that other batch file it adds a new encryption for those 36 letters and numbers into that document. So I'm trying to define within the other batch file which specific and unique frequency it should use to decrypt the text

Comment: That batch file could also be modified to change the output! You're effectively trying to get us to fix an issue you've caused by poor design, instead of fixing the design. Whilst I'm sure we could try to solve the issue you've created, it would be better, if you just take a step back and try to create something simpler, instead of continually working around relatively complex situations which did not need to exist in the first place. BTW, How many different sets of key pairs are you writing to that file, I mean theres only twenty three minures between those two you've shown.

Comment: This is a link to the entire script. I'm not entirely sure what you mean tbh
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZci0L5lKcnZ3SICREoq4vWq5I8kVpj3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is there any way I can show you the script then? It's over 6800 lines long and contains about 170000 characters lol. So I can't really send it here

Comment: [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/Vknh6/1234) This is ghostbin. If it asks for password it's 1234

Comment: The password for the batch file itself however is `admin02`

Comment: I am not understanding why you would write the same variable names to a file multiple times.  That is complicating the matter.  I got 42 years in I.T. and programming and can't say I have ever run into a situation where I would do that.

Comment: To start at a certain line use the `skip` option of [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (perhaps based on the output of `find /V /N "=" "decryption_key.txt"`?). To stop after a certain number of lines, implement a counter and check its value in the loop. But anyway, perhaps you do not need the latter when you just put `if defined %%G` in front of `set "%%G=%%H"`, given that all the `key_*` variables are initially undefined (which can be ensured by `for /F "delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul set "key_"') do set "%%V="` at the beginning of your script)…

Comment: The reason for doing that is to log the specific encryption key's of each letter into that file so that the message you encrypted can be decrypted again. Each time you open the batch file it generates new frequencies for each letter meaning that if it did a overwrite of the old logged frequencies the messages encrypted with those frequencies would be lost forever. And would never be able to be decrypted again

Comment: Eg. You encrypt message "hi" during that encryption the key is set to
"h = .." and "i = ...."
But the next time you write the same message it would be something different. Meaning that if you lost the original frequency your text was encrypted with. It would be lost forever

Comment: @Gabrielnigme20, this would be easier using a more capable language. In PowerShell, a set of lines in the middle of a file can be read using `Get-Content -Path .\afile.txt | Select-Object -Index (22..29)`.

Comment: I find it hard to believe your pseudo encryption and decryption method works. If you encrypt the letter S to be an asterisk and you encrypted the letters SS it would be two asterisks. But, when you decrypt the the two asterisks it becomes an O.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, here's a small section of the code to show you how I fixed the problem

```
:sdeckeya
title Koral Coder mega menu (Scanning key frequencies...)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="
0^<"decryption_key.txt"') do set "%%G=%%H" & set /a break=%loopcount%+35 & goto read_decryption_key
:sdec
title Koral Coder mega menu (Awaiting input...)
color 7
set loopcount=0
set "ukey="
set "key_a="
set "break="
cls
echo Please insert the decryption key file to the following directory:
echo %~dp0
echo Make sure that the name of the decryption key is "decryption_key.txt"
echo.
echo Which decryption key within the "decryption_key.txt" file would you like to use?
echo Each new key is defined by a date and time of creation. The first key is "1" the next is "2" and so on.
echo.
echo Example:
echo (THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF THE DOCUMENT)
echo Date encrypted: 17/06/2021 Time: 16.55.53,20 ^<^<^<^<^<^<^<^<^< This is key 1 (for each time a new "Date ecnrypted:" occurs, is a new key 1 number higher than the previous)
echo key_a=xxxx
echo key_b=xxxx
echo ...
echo Date encrypted: 17/06/2021 Time: 16.55.53,20 ^<^<^<^<^<^<^<^<^< This is key 2 (for each time a new "Date ecnrypted:" occurs, is a new key 1 number higher than the previous)
echo key_a=xxxx
echo key_b=xxxx
echo ...
echo and so on
echo.
echo Type "exit" to go back to the main menu
echo.
set /p ukey= KeyNumber: 
if not defined ukey goto sdec
if "%ukey%"==" " goto sdec
if %ukey%==exit goto unlock
if %ukey%==1 (
set /a loopcount=%loopcount%+%ukey%
goto sdeckeya
)
if %ukey% NEQ 1 set /a loopcount=%loopcount%+36
if %ukey% NEQ 1 set /a loopcount=%loopcount%*%ukey%
if %ukey% NEQ 1 set /a loopcount=%loopcount%-36
if %ukey% NEQ 1 set /a break=%ukey%*36
if %loopcount%==-36 goto sdecfail 
goto read_decryption_key
:sdecfail
title Koral Coder mega menu (ERROR - no letters)
cls
color 4
echo ERROR!
echo Please only use numbers to define which decryption key you want to use
echo.
pause
goto sdec
:read_decryption_key
title Koral Coder mega menu (Scanning key frequencies...)
cls
color 7
if %loopcount% NEQ %break% (
for /f "tokens=1,* skip=%loopcount% delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="
0^<"decryption_key.txt"') do set "%%G=%%H" & goto breakcheck
) else goto filecheck
:breakcheck
set /a loopcount=%loopcount%+1
echo Loading key frequencies please wait...
echo %loopcount%
goto read_decryption_key
:filecheck
```